# SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi .NetCLR

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx, coreclr

Trying to compile this code with Dnx CoreCLR

```
passValue = new byte[pass.Length];
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(pinValue, GCHandleType.Pinned);
ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi(pass); //Here NET CLR 
Marshal.Copy(ptr, passValue, 0, passValue.Length);
passValueLen = Convert.ToUInt32(passValue.Length);
```

I am getting this error

> CS0117: 'Marshal' does not contain a definition for
>   'SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi'

I am sure there is a workaround to marshal the securestring in core CLR.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. May you please specify your OS, version of .net/mono framework you use, and what's your intent with marshalling a SecureString (passing the string to unmanaged code I guess) ?

Comment: corrclr on Windows 2012 server

Answer (score -1):

#### The Answer is often in the Source

Since Microsoft has opened the source of the .NET framework, it is now quite easy and legal to look at the implementation of each classes and grab any useful information.

- [The sources of CLR which includes mscorlib and the VM](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr)
- [The sources of BCL which may not be completely uploaded yet](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)

From that, you can find that  `Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi(pass)` 
is more or less a call to `SecureString.ToAnsiStr`.

**`SecureString`** is part of **System.Security** namespace and in **mscorlib.dll**

**Note:**
Some methods of .NET framework are not written to work outside of a Win32 environment, especially those relying on Interop, COM, extern calls to VM.
From [documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/choosing-the-right-dotnet.html), you can see that

> .NET Core 5 is a modular runtime and library implementation that
>   includes a subset of the .NET Framework

So, only a subset of the framework features may work. However you can run DNX on Mono as well. In the case, you're trying to run the code on Unix, or Android environment, you should give a try to Mono instead, because they are a little bit ahead in terms of supported features on these platforms.

**DNX** has been retired as specified [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) and you should now use [CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli).

Here is an extract of [securestring.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Security/securestring.cs)

```
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
#if FEATURE_CORRUPTING_EXCEPTIONS
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] 
#endif // FEATURE_CORRUPTING_EXCEPTIONS
    internal unsafe IntPtr ToAnsiStr(bool allocateFromHeap) {
        EnsureNotDisposed();

        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;          
        int byteCount = 0;
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();                        
        try {
            // GetAnsiByteCount uses the string data, so the calculation must happen after we are decrypted.
            UnProtectMemory();

            // allocating an extra char for terminating zero
            byteCount = GetAnsiByteCount() + 1; 

            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
            try {
            }
            finally {
                if( allocateFromHeap) {
                    ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byteCount);
                }
                else {
                    ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(byteCount);
               }                    
            }

            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }

            GetAnsiBytes((byte *)ptr.ToPointer(), byteCount);
            result = ptr;                
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            ProtectMemory();
            throw;
        }
        finally {
            ProtectMemory();
            if( result == IntPtr.Zero) { 
                // If we failed for any reason, free the new buffer
                if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    Win32Native.ZeroMemory(ptr, (UIntPtr)byteCount);
                    if( allocateFromHeap) {                                                    
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                    }
                    else {
                        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);                            
                    }
                }                    
            }                

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error  CS0117: 'SecureString' does not contain a definition for 'ToAnsiStr'

Comment: @Ibrahim it would help if you specify on which OS you run DNX

Comment: on Windows 2012 Server

Comment: ToAnsiStr is a private function although can be overriden